# What type of chart would you choose in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a requirement for making a chart in ssrs but I can't understand this chart is which type in SSRS.

Here is the current chart

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say based on the information you have given.

- It could be a standard `Column` Chart with the Y axis set to show negative numbers, or
- It could be a `Stock`, `CandleStick`, or `Bloxplot` type

It's very difficult to tell without some context of what data it is reporting on.

Comment: I did't got your answer

Comment: ? You do not understand it? You don't agree with it? It is very difficult based on what you've told us to know 'how' to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

When I started creating SSRS charts, What I did was to create different chart for a report and I will finally chose the one I am most pleased with to be published. You can play around with different charts and take it from there

Comment: I did't got your answer